# Add animation to changing elements in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm displaying 4 divs by `v-for` loop of data from backend call:

```
<b-col v-for="n in articles" :key="n.id" class="random__record">
```

`articles` variable is JSON gathered in backend call

```
methods: {
    async getData() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/api/article/getRandom.php`, axiosConfig);
            this.articles = response.data.records;
            console.log(this.articles);
        } catch (e) {
            this.errors.push(e)
        }
    }
},
```

I'm changing this 4 elements by executing this `getData()` function every 20 seconds:

```
mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.getData();
    }, 20000);
},
```

I'm trying to fade-out and fade-in this 4 elements, so it would look nicer, not changing immedietaly but nice fading out and then 4 new fading in. I tried to add `transition: 1s all` to `.random__record` class but it didn't make it done.

```
.random__record {
    transition: 1s all;
}
```

How I can add animation of fade-out and fade-in 4 new elements here?

Comment: I think you need to show the working code. For example, on jsfiddle.

Comment: Transition property has wrong parameters.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp